# Opening Links under current window?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to opening links in current window itself.
for ex:

- About
- Contact us
- Daily user

The default link is "about". Only one must display at a time (while the other 2 links hide). How can I do this?

If I click "About" (It displays like below:)

- About
- Contact us
- Daily user

About 
    ....................................... 
    ......................................

If I click "Contact Us" (It displays like below)

- About
- Contact us
- Daily user

Contact Us 
    ....................................... 
    ......................................

Comment: what do you mean by opening the links?

Comment: I have above three links in one page. If i click "About" only display about. or if i click "Contact us" only display contact us... pls give some idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery accordian. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ ) or Jquery tabs. I think Jquery tabs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) will be good for you.

Comment: if it was helpful you can vote or accept the answe :)